# No logro usar el .json de un api

Tags: api, response

Alguien sabe por que estoy haciendo mal, pues quiero obtener trabajar con esta api de riot y usar el .json que veo cuando accedo al link.
lo único que retorna cuando uso este código es un "response" y sin el .json.

PDT: en el link, después del "api-ket=" es una llave que caduca, lo renovare cuando alguein me lo solicite para la ayuda

a continuación el código:

```
fetch('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/Einstein?api_key=RGAPI-998c0637-97db-4460-a57f-55db7b9c2f36', {
        method: "GET",          
        mode: "no-cors",
        redirect:"follow",
        Headers : new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        cache: 'default',
        }),
    }) 

  .then((response) => {     
        console.log(response)       
  })
```

Comment: Prueba con `console.log(response.json())`, pero me parece que tu content-type además debiera ser `application/json`

Comment: Me retorna error, .json is not function ... no se por que retorna este error si .json es un metodo de reponse

Comment: A lo mejor al poner `no-cors` te está devolviendo una respuesta opaca, que es una instancia de response pero no tiene nada.

Comment: Hice la prueba con una de mis API y efectivamente al poner `no-cors` evitas el error de `Allow-Origin` pero la respuesta es opaca. Tienes que quitar esa línea, y si no puedes acceder al API desde el browser, tendrás que probar haciendo la petición desde el backend. No puedo hacer la prueba con la URL que pusiste porque tu llave caducó

Comment: Acabo de editar la key para que sirva el link, quito la linea de `no-cors` o cambio a `cors` de igual manera se retorna error ... para ser mas exacto `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Lo cual significa que tienes que hacer el request desde el backend

Answer (score 0):

`fetch(...)` es un `Promise` que devuelve un objeto `response`.
Adentro del objeto response tienes el metodo `json()` que a su ves, devuelve un `Promise`.

```js
fetch('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/Einstein?api_key=RGAPI-998c0637-97db-4460-a57f-55db7b9c2f36', {
      method: "GET",          
      mode: "no-cors",
      redirect:"follow",
      Headers : {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      cache: 'default',
      },
  })
  .then((response) => {
    response.json().then((data) => {
      console.dir(data)
    })       
  })
```

### Async/Await

Si estas trabajando con soporte `async/await`, puedes escribir de esta manera

```js
const getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v3/summoners/by-name/Einstein?api_key=RGAPI-998c0637-97db-4460-a57f-55db7b9c2f36', {
    method: "GET",          
    mode: "no-cors",
    redirect:"follow",
    Headers : {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      cache: 'default',
    }})
  return await response.json()
}

(async () => {
  const data = await getData()
  console.dir(data)
})()
```

Comment: Utilice ambas recomendaciones y sale error en consola, como yo hago el fecth me retorna el `response`, pero el metodo `response.ok` da `false` y `response.json` no dan acceso, es extraño, cambie de link pensando que era los servidores y tengo el mismo problema ...

Comment: cuando response.ok es `false`, prueba lo siguiente `if (!response.ok) { console.log(response.statusText);}` cual es el mensaje de error que recibes?

Comment: en consola no sale nada, igual cuando despliego en consola las propiedades  de`response` este es el resultado `body
:
(...)`,`bodyUsed
:
false`,`ok
:
false`,`redirected
:
false`,`status
:
0`,`statusText
:
""`,`type
:
"opaque"`,`url
:
""`